# I need to post data that I want to receive as Dictionary<string,string> in my controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to post data that I want to receive as Dictionary in my controller.
How I can send it through $.ajax so that I may receive it Dictionary

Comment: Create an associative array and send it as JSON. In your controller deserialize it to your type of dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Binding to a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Also be aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366797/passing-dictionarystring-object-to-mvc-controller